# type mismatch in kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm newbie to Kotlin language and Object Oriented Programming, so I wonder why  there's a wrong type of instance of the class inherited from class Fragment() in android. These are my codes

#### Fragment.kt

```
 class MyFragment: Fragment() {
 //do something
 }
```

#### MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
val fm : Fragment? = MyFragment()
...
}
```

Why fm return **MyFragment** type, not **Fragment?** ??
Thank you

Comment: Prolly because it's a Fragment from different package

Comment: What you mean by 'fm return MyFragment type'? How do you check this?

Comment: @Selvin 2 files are in the same package

Comment: Seems like you do not understand .... show the imports or ask a fairy ... there is no class called `Fragment` ... its `com.example.some.package.Fragment` or `com.example.some.different.package.Fragment`

Comment: After I build my project, there's a message error: " Type mismatch: inferred type is MyFragment but Fragment? was expected" @guenhter

Comment: Thanks, @Selvin , you save my day

Answer (score 1):

I'm so silly that I import 2 different packages for Fragment()

The solution is that 2 files must be imported android.app.Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 changeFragment(MyFragment())
```

method should be like this

```
    fun changeFragment(f: Fragment, cleanStack: Boolean = false) {
    val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (cleanStack) {
        clearBackStack();
    }        
    ft.replace(R.id.activity_base_content, f);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
   }

    fun clearBackStack() {
    val manager = supportFragmentManager;
    if (manager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
        val first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
        manager.popBackStack(first.id, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
     }
     }
```